# Ubuntu on my computer

Tags: 11.04

I just want you to say me if Ubuntu would run smoothly (I meam, not without too much lags and freezing) on my computer.
Here are the specs:

Intel Pentium 4 CPU 2.40 GHz, 512 MB RAM, Intel 82845G/GL/GE/PE/GV Grpahics Controller

Now, I´m runnig Windows XP , but it´s not smooth enough

Can you help me ? Tank you very much :)

Answer (score 2):

it might be that Ubuntu would be running slowly on your system. I think Ubuntu (with Unity) is too much too handle for your computer to run smoothly.

I recommend to check out Xubuntu or Lubuntu. It is basically Ubuntu with a more lightweight window manager. Those distros should run perfectly on your computer.

Xubuntu: http://xubuntu.org/

Lubuntu: http://lubuntu.net/